# Automatic extraction of data from google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, data-extraction

We usually import data from google analytics once a month and use it for some reporting needs internally. The problem is that we have to do this manually and it would be nice if we could automate the process and potentially increase the once a month routine to once a week or even daily. Our ultimate goal would be to have a tool set up to import the data automatically and store it to a csv or excel file. The output file doesn't really matter to us. As long as we can have the data pulled from GA on a regular basis without manual intervention, we'll take care of what to do with the data once it's here. We use some java based executable (found online) for this but we run this manually to extract the data.

I have looked for some solutions, even open source tools(.Net preferably, anything but java based really) but I have not really found anything. most of them require manual intervention to export data, and the best they can do is have reports generated automatically based on that data.

Our last resort would be to write up something ourselves but I would like research this a bit further and save developing/programming time. I am pretty sure someone out there has at least encounter/though of this problem.

Any help, pointers or redirection to better sources would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: would simple excel pluging (for example excellent analytics) be considered to be a solution?

Comment: Thanks @PetrHavlík. I checked it out and it doesn't really automate the job the way I want it to. I want to be able to set it up and it would run by itself on a weekly basis without me having to launch anything.

Comment: Then also check out Analytics Canvas, which is a priced tool though...

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the [Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/) or [Google Analytic's Magic Script](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/report-automation-magic)? These would allow you to pull data into Google Spreadsheets on a regular basis. Specifically, the Magic Script will allow you to setup triggers to run a function on reoccurring time interval E.g. daily, weekly, monthly, etc.

Comment: Yeah you know, I'm actually exploring the Google Apps Script tools to see if I can come up with something. Thanks